# Rails 4: Moving Active Record generated collections from view to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Starting with Rails and I would like to move ORM part from view to model.

How to do it?

Example:

```
 <%= f.collection_check_boxes :instructor_ids, Instructor.joins(:events).where(events: { :start_time => Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today.end_of_week }).group("instructor_id").having("count(instructor_id) < 4"), :id, :name do |ib| %>
  <%= ib.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {ib.check_box(class: "checkbox") + ib.text } %>
 <% end %>
```

Thanks.

Luiz,

Thanks for pointing me to scopes. I solved this as follows.

```
 app/views/events/_form.html.erb

 <%= f.collection_check_boxes :instructor_ids, Event.instructor_week_limit, :id, :name do |ib| %>
  <%= ib.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {ib.check_box(class: "checkbox") + ib.text } %>
 <% end %>
```

app/models/event.rb

```
  scope :instructors_this_week, -> { Instructor.joins(:events).where(events: { :start_time => Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today.end_of_week }) }
  scope :instructor_week_limit, -> { instructors_this_week.group("instructor_id").having("count(instructor_id) < 4") }
```

Comment: Well, it's a nice move, do it. P.S. Or do you have any actual questions concerning the process?

Answer (score 2):

Scopes should do the work for you. You still gonna use collection_check_boxes, but only defining the relationship ids. This guide will help you:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#applying-a-default-scope

best!

Comment: glad to be helpful =)